# r knit word document rotate single plot

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am trying to rotate a single plot so in a knit word document using R-Studio. Where I would expect the rotated plot I just get a blank space. Here is the source of my .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "rotate-test"
output: word_document
---

Un-rotated plot:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Attempt to rotate:

```{r, echo=FALSE, out.extra='angle=90'}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: might not be implemented yet for .Rmd files. see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/301

Comment: `out.extra='angle=90'` is for LaTeX only. There is no way to do that for Word, AFAIK.